# How to compare a string in Java with another string stored in hbase with case-insensitive?

Tags: java, string, hbase, case-insensitive

I am new to HBase.

I want to compare a string in Java with another string stored in hbase with case-insensitive.

How can i achieve this ?

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 0):

You could try RegexStringComparator like

```
RegexStringComparator regexStringComparator = new RegexStringComparator("^[aA][bB][cC]$");//will match aBc or ABC or Abc any case in order of a followed by b followed by c.
SingleColumnValueFilter filter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(
    cf,
    column,
    CompareOp.EQUAL,
    regexStringComparator
    );
scan.setFilter(filter);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to compare with db itself. if it matches then only it should retrieve the content.

Comment: Currently I am using SingleColumnValueFilter to compare string.

Comment: SubstringComparator will help?

Comment: I tried . But it returns true even if half of the word is matches. Because as the name implies it is a Substring comparator.

Comment: ok. i will try this. but the above regex will match only for 'abc' ? can you provide the regex for alphanumeric ?

Comment: Sure, yes it will just match abc and let me know how it goes. Alphanumeric would be [a-zA-Z0-9]*