# Python HBase: Ignore case of the entered value when filtering database

Tags: python-2.7, hadoop, flask, hbase, thrift

I am writing a API in python2.7(flask), I want to fetch the data(Database- Hbase) ignoring the case of the entered value(value may also contain special characters, spaces, multiple words, numeric value).

How can I accomplish this?

Example value Entered : tom, jery, tom+jery, tom and jery, tom1+, 1jery2

Match to respective value in the table: Tom, Jery, TOM+JERY, Tom And Jery, Tom1+, 1JERY2

Here is my code:

```
class MyClass:
    def my_fun(self, param_1, param_2):
        result = SearchResult(param_1, param_2)
        result.properties = {k:v for (k,v) in properties.iteritems() if my_value in 
        v}   
        return result
```

How to ignore case of my_value where v is a list/string

Thank you very much!

Comment: How should "ab, cde" match to "Ab Cdet"??? Is that a typo? Can you accurately describe how the comparison should match? Without more information, I won't be able to answer your question.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. Here is the example.
Value Entered: cat, dog, cat1, dog+2, i love Dogs, Cat+dog
Should Match Value in the Table: Cat, Dog, Cat1, Dog+2, I Love Dogs, CAT+DOG

I want to ignore the case and fetch the data.

Comment: @wovano Please let me know if you need any more clarity.

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of posting new information in comments. NB: Since you seem to be new at Stack Overflow, please read the [tour], [ask] and how to create a [mre].

Comment: @wovano Here is an example in Java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27738735/how-to-compare-a-string-in-java-with-another-string-stored-in-hbase-with-case-in